# Convert string to DD:HH:MM:SS C#?

Tags: c#, sql, date, datetime

I am reading a string from an XML file in this format. DD:HH:MM:SS. This string tells me the duration of a test run. I want to try to get the sum of how long all the tests take in a month, but I'm unsure if there is a way to convert the string to a timestamp in this format. I am aware of using Convert.ToDateTime, but unfortunately I will never have a month or year in the string that is being read in. I'm not entirely sure if this is even possible, but is there anyway to do something like this in C#, and if not, any other suggestions?? All help would be appreciated, Thanks!

```
var test = "00.00.00.14";
var final = Convert.ToDateTime("dd:hh:mm:ss"); //Any way to do something like this? This format throws an error
```

Comment: I don't know why you would want to convert to a datetime. It's not for a measurement of elapsed time. Maybe you're looking for timespam?

Comment: See the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan.aspx) (a duration), not [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) (a point in time). Specifically, the [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370.aspx) method lets you specify the format it should try to read.

```
var result = TimeSpan.ParseExact("00.00.00.14", @"dd\.hh\.mm\.ss",
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`TimeSpan`s can be summed, e.g.

```
var sum = timeSpan1 + timeSpan2;
```